# On infinite alternative function series

Tags: calculus

I try to calculate numerically approximation of the following series 
$$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } e^{-k} (-1)^k=\frac{e}{1+e}=0.731059$$
$$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } (-1)^k J_0\left(2 \sqrt{k}\right)=0.746544$$
The Logica serie go on 
$$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{x^k}{(k!)^3}=\, _0F_2(;1,1;x)$$
$$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } (-1)^k \, _0F_2(;1,1;k)$$ but here come the problem Mathematica say the series no converge but using other methods we could get
$$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } (-1)^k \, _0F_2(;1,1;k)=0.749421$$
go on the series
$$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } (-1)^k \, _0F_3(;1,1,1;k)=0.749904$$
A fault of Mathematica  algorithm??

Comment: The summand of the last two series does not tend to $0$. Mathematica is right. Could you please clarify the method you use?

Comment: Do you mind to explicit *using other methods we could get* ? Thanks

Comment: the function is too oscillate for example $$\text{Table}\left[\left\{\, _0F_2(;1,1;-k)\right\},\{k,190,210\}\right]$$  $$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 47.0779 \\
 43.0995 \\
 38.9905 \\
 34.752 \\
 30.3852 \\
 25.8913 \\
 21.2715 \\
 16.5274 \\
 11.6605 \\
 6.67226 \\
 1.56453 \\
 -3.66091 \\
 -9.00217 \\
 -14.4572 \\
 -20.024 \\
 -25.7004 \\
 -31.484 \\
 -37.3725 \\
 -43.3635 \\
 -49.4544 \\
 -55.6426 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$